# ¿Cómo habilitar o deshabilitar Button si al menos un Checkbox está habilitado?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy tratando de habilitar o deshabilitar dos Buttons dependiendo si algún Checkbox está habilitado. Tengo un Checkbox por cada registro en mi tabla HTML, les dejo foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tengo solo un Checkbox habilitado, sí me habilita los 2 Buttons. Pero el problema es cuando tengo habilitados dos o más Checkbox, si vuelvo a deshabilitar uno, también se deshabilitan los Buttons, aunque tenga más Checkbox habilitados.

Este es mi código JQuery:

```
`function disableSending(select) {
    if (select.checked) {
        $('.ar').prop('disabled',false);
    } else {
        $('.ar').prop('disabled',true);
    }
}`
```

Este es el HTML:

```
`<input type="checkbox" name="select" id="select" value="<?php echo $row['idIvms']; ?>" onclick="disableSending(this);">

<button type="submit" title="Aceptar" name="accept" id="accept" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-circle btn-sm mx-1 ar">
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
</button>

<button type="submit" title="Rechazar" name="reject" id="reject" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-circle btn-sm mx-1 ar">
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
</button>`
```

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes verificar si al menos un *checkbox* está marcado, obteniendo todos, agregando al final del selector el atributo [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) y contando el total con la propiedad [.length](https://api.jquery.com/length/):

```
function disableSending(select) {
    // Buscar todos los checkbox con nombre select y que estén marcados
    if($('input[name="select"]:checked').length > 0) {
        // Al menos hay un checkbox marcado, habilitar botón
        $('.ar').prop('disabled',false);
    } else {
        // No hay checkbox marcado, deshabilitar botón
        $('.ar').prop('disabled',true);
    }
}
```

Comment: funciona amigo pero al cargar la página por primera vez, todos los checkbox están deshabilitados y los buttons habilitados

Comment: Ya lo resolví amigo, solo faltaba agregarle el atributo "disabled" a los buttons para que por defecto estuvieran deshabilitados. Muchas gracias bro